# SQL - Count cases when a user navigates away from a specific site section

Tags: sql

I have a table of site page views. I want to list and count visits to a site section on the page view directly after a user navigates away from 'articles'.

Here's an example table of page views:

| User | Site Section | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | articles | 1/1/2000 01:01:00 |
| A | sports | 1/1/2000 01:02:00 |
| B | sports | 1/1/2000 01:01:00 |
| B | articles | 1/1/2000 01:02:00 |
| B | weather | 1/1/2000 01:03:00 |
| C | articles | 1/1/2000 01:01:00 |
| C | articles | 1/1/2000 01:02:00 |
| C | articles | 1/1/2000 01:03:00 |
| C | weather | 1/1/2000 01:04:00 |
| C | sports | 1/1/2000 01:05:00 |

In the case above, I want my query to show the following:

| Site Section | Count |
| --- | --- |
| weather | 2 |
| sports | 1 |

I tried creating a WITH subquery of something like

`SELECT distinct user_id, site_section, row_number() over(partition by user_ID, site_section ORDER BY derived_timestamp) as navigation`

and then selecting cases site section = 'articles' and then adding +1 to the rank but it was still returning articles because I'm unsure how to take a +1 if the site section still reads articles. I would want to skip those cases

Answer (score 0):

You can utilise `lag()` here to identify if the visit immediately follows "articles"

```
with c as (
  select SiteSection,
    case when 'articles' = Lag(SiteSection) over(partition by "user" order by timestamp) then 1 end Cnt
  from t
)
select SiteSection, Sum(Cnt) "Count"
from c
where SiteSection !='articles'
group by SiteSection;
```